# How works Semaphore Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, semaphore

I want to check the reachability of about 100 ips addresses and set a limit of concurrent tasks with semaphore. But now I'm not sure how this works exactly or why it doesn't work in the code example. As I could observe the function "task_reachable" is still executed correctly. if no address is reachable, then in the "try_ssh_connection" "all" tasks are executed in parallel and this makes the code incredibly slow.

```
class test_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = "username"
        self.password = "password"

        self.ips = open("open_ip_list")

    def create_async(self):

        asyncio.run(self.create_tasks())

    async def boundary_task(self,ip):
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
        async with sem:
            return await self.task_test(ip)

    async def create_tasks(self):
        timer = Timer(text=f" task time: {{:.1f}}")
        timer.start()
        tasks = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.boundary_task(i))
            for i
            in self.ips
        ]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        timer.stop()

    async def task_test(self):
        pass
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = test_class()
    app.create_async()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is each running instance of `boundary_task` has its own semaphore.

```
async def boundary_task(self, ip):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
```

If you want them to all use the same semaphore, all instances of `boundary_task` need to share it.

```
async def boundary_task(self, ip, semaphore):
    async with sem:
        return await self.task_reachable(ip)

async def create_tasks(self):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
    tasks = [
        self.boundary_task(i, sem)
        for i
        in self.ips
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Since you are using a class, you could also create the semaphore inside `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...

    self.sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)

async def boundary_task(self, ip):
    async with self.sem:
        return await self.task_reachable(ip)
```